# how to reference elements in CSS or JS files for fastest parsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, webpage-rendering

I'm trying to improve a websites rendering speed.

Both CSS and JS files mostly reference elements like this:

Javascript:

```
   $('.some_element').doSth()
```

CSS:

```
   .some_element { /* do something */ }
```

Just curious - is this the optimal way of referencing elements in terms of javascript parsing and website rendering? Wouldn't it be better to do something like **div.some_element**?

Thanks for some infos!

Comment: you are trying to compare css rendering to jquery selector DOM search which makes no sense since they operate with different engines

Comment: not comparing. I was just curious as to how to reference both the optimal way. thx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is a priority you might want to switch to [vanilla javascript](http://sharedfil.es/js-48hIfQE4XK.html) as much as you can. Native javascript is faster than jQuery.

If you want to keep your jQuery selector use parent context to make the search for the element more efficient. Example $('#parent').find(child)

You can find more tips on javascript an jquery optimization on the web:
http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/12/3-tips-make-your-jquery-selectors-faster/

Answer (score 2):

`div.some_element` will be different than `.some_element`, if you don't just have divs that use the some_element class.

Maybe compare render times using Chrome's built-in developer tools (or an alternative) to see if it helps you, but I doubt it'll be significant.

Comment: most of the classes always refer to the same element. Checking Chrome dev tools. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to find a single element is usually with an id, not a class:

```
document.getElementById("whatever")
```

If you have to use jQuery (which is not as fast as plain javascript), then you would use:

```
$("#whatever")
```

If speed is really important, you can resolve the DOM element once when the page loads and just save the direct DOM reference so you don't have to find it when your code actually executes later.

As with all questions of performance, the only real way to answer a performance question is to benchmark a couple of implementation options and actually test which is faster.